# Как организовать периодическую отправку данных на сервер

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, background-task, backgroundworker

Строго каждые 3 минуты нужно отправлять на сервер запрос с информацией о действиях клиента. Например, нажал ли он определенную кнопку, и если нажал, то слать запрос на получение данных. Состояние кнопки нужно отслеживать даже если пользователь свернул приложение. (Может показаться, что состояние кнопки отслеживать в фоне смысла нет - кнопка только ради примера, задача же будет требовать мониторинга состояния даже в фоне)

Я знаю, что есть `background modes`, из них для меня (я так понял) подходит либо `background fetch`, либо `executing finite-length tasks`. Но сразу поправка, в `background fetch` я могу установить интервал выполнения запросов, `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval`, который не гарантирует **строго каждые 3 минуты**. А сомнения по поводу `executing finite-length tasks` в том, что мне надо выполнить 2-3 запроса (как понял, через NSTimer), и сама по себе задача не является длительной.

Что следует использовать? Может мне вообще следует это выполнять через `NSURLSession`, но тогда в каком направлении копать?

Comment: если надо ну вот совсем точно каждые три, то наверно только если держать приложение активным через воспроизведение аудио. При этом, надо имеено что иметь какое то аудио, которое по мнению ревьюеров из эпл будет иметь смысл (не пустой трек). я бы пердлложил каждые три минуты посредством аудио оповещать пользователя, что происходит обновление. (типа как беговые приложения каждый километр тебе говорят, что ты пробежал еще километр)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko как всегда, рад Вас видеть :з, не будет ли проблем с тем, что я уведомляю пользователя не через пуш, а какими то иными методами?

Comment: честно скажу, сам такого не делал - как то недавно наткнулся на статью, где кто-то объяснял как они провернули такой фокус.проблем вроде быть не должно, но честно говоря, я бы все таки посоветовал делать background fetch (хотя он и не гарантирует отправку точно по времени)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko если пробовать делать через bg fetch, то как посоветуете тестировать это? Я поставил минимальный интервал отправки 3 минуты, в виде теста делал какой то корректный асинхронный запрос в гугл, и сразу же в замыкании запроса, выдавал локальную нотификацию о времени действии, запустил и никаких результатов, только если симулировать запрос

Comment: проверьте, что ваши локальные уведомления работают - в ios8 добавили такую фишку, что надо сначала у пользователя спросить разрешения; либо после получения запроса сохраняйте что нить в user defaults, что позже можно проверить; либо сделайте сервер на localHost и проверяйте со стороны сервера, что запрос приходил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В фоне система не позволит тебе отправлять данные каждые 3 минуты постоянно. 
Подробнее можно почитать о возможностях работы в фоне: 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-..

Есть хак с аудио воспроизведением (когда играется пустой трек), то приложение живет и можно отправлять запросы в нужное время. Если пользователь не прервет воспроизведение и приложение должно обязательно находится в фоне.

Или например отслеживать по локации. У locationManager есть свойство которое позволяет запускать метод делегата с определенной периодичностью, будить приложение и отправлять данные. Если не ошибаюсь это возможно только с ios8.

Единственное НО, в вероятность того, что такое приложение попадет в app store стремится к нулю)